# Reseting variables to a previous state

Tags: python, variables

```
import sys, os, random

class player():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.level=1
        self.sword="Laser Sword"
        self.armour="Titanium Armour"
        self.maxhealth=100
        self.health=self.maxhealth
        self.gold=10
        self.pots=0
        self.attack=0
        if self.sword=="Wooden Sword":
            self.attack=10
        elif self.sword=="Tin Greatsword":
            self.attack=15
        elif self.sword=="Iron Greatsword":
            self.attack=20
        elif self.sword=="Ice Sword":
            self.attack=30
        elif self.sword=="Earth Sword":
            self.attack=35
        elif self.sword=="Fire Sword":
            self.attack=40
        elif self.sword=="Laser Sword":
            self.attack=50
        else:
            self.attack=0

class goblin():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.maxhealth=50
        self.health=self.maxhealth
        self.attack=5
        self.goldgain=10
goblinIG=goblin("Goblin")

class zombie():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.maxhealth=70
        self.health=self.maxhealth
        self.attack=7
        self.goldgain=15
zombieIG=zombie("Zombie")

class skeleton():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.maxhealth=90
        self.health=self.maxhealth
        self.attack=8
        self.goldgain=20
skeletonIG=skeleton("Skeleton")

def main():
    os.system('clear')
    print "Welcome to Inspire!"
    print "1.) Start"
    print "2.) Tutorial"
    print "3.) Load"
    print "4.) Exit"
    option=raw_input("-->")
    if option=="1":
        start()
    elif option=="2":
        tutorial()
    elif option=="3":
        pass
    elif option=="4":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        main()

def tutorial():
    print "Welcome to Inspire, the text-based RPG game."
    print "Inspire is a game about the hero (you) going on an adventure and fighting monsters."
    print "When go and fight you are meeted with a info screen."
    print "Player    vs    Enemy"
    print "All the stats"
    print "You know have a option to Attack, Drink a potion(that's if you have any), or to run away."
    print "Note that it isn't guaranteed that you will get away."
    print "If you attack you will deal damage to the enemy,"
    print "Press enter to see what the enemy does,"
    print "After this it will go back to the info screen for the fight,"
    print "Once again you have the three choices."
    print ""
    print "If decide not to fight then you can go to the store."
    print "In the store you can buy new weapons, armour and potions from the gold you get when you will an enemy."
    print "That is all you need to know."
    print "Have fun playing, Inspire"
    print ""
    print "Press enter to go back to the main menu."
    option=raw_input("")
    main()


def start():
    os.system('clear')
    print "Hello! What is your name?"
    option=raw_input("-->")
    global playerIG
    playerIG=player(option)
    start1()

def start1():
    os.system('clear')
    print "Player Stats:"
    print "Name: %s" % playerIG.name.title()
    print "Level: %s" % playerIG.level
    print "Health: %i/%i" % (playerIG.health,playerIG.maxhealth)
    print "Sword: %s" % playerIG.sword
    print "Armour: %s" % playerIG.armour
    print "Average Damage: %i" % playerIG.attack
    print "Gold: %i" % playerIG.gold
    print "1.) Fight"
    print "2.) Store"
    print "3.) Save"
    print "4.) Exit"
    option=raw_input("-->")
    if option=="1":
        preFight()
    elif option=="2":
        store()
    elif option=="3":
        pass
    elif option=="4":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        start1()

def preFight():
    global enemy
    enemynum=random.randint(1,3)
    if enemynum==1:
        enemy=goblinIG
    elif enemynum==2:
        enemy=zombieIG
    elif enemynum==3:
        enemy=skeletonIG
    fight()

def fight():
    print "%s    vs    %s" % (playerIG.name, enemy.name)
    print "%s's Health: %i/%i" % (playerIG.name.title(), playerIG.health, playerIG.maxhealth)
    print "%s's Health: %i/%i" % (enemy.name, enemy.health, enemy.maxhealth)
    print "Potions: %s" % (playerIG.pots)
    print "1.) Attack"
    print "2.) Drink Potion"
    print "3.) Run"
    option=raw_input("-->")
    if option=="1":
        attack()
    elif option=="2":
        drinkpot()
    elif option=="3":
        run()
    else:
        fight()

def attack():
    os.system('clear')
    pAttack=random.randint(playerIG.attack/2, playerIG.attack)
    eAttack=random.randint(enemy.attack/2, enemy.attack)
    if pAttack==playerIG.attack/2:
        print "You miss!"
    else:
        enemy.health-=pAttack
        print "You deal %s damage" % pAttack
    option=raw_input("")
    os.system('clear')
    if eAttack==enemy.attack/2:
        print "The enemy missed!"
    else:
        if playerIG.armour=="Iron Armour":
            playerIG.health-=eAttack/1.5
            print "The enemy deals %s damage" % eAttack
        elif playerIG.armour=="Heavy Iron Armour":
            playerIG.health-=eAttack/2.5
            print "The enemy deals %s damage" % eAttack
        elif playerIG.armour=="Titanium Armour":
            playerIG.health-=eAttack/3
            print "The enemy deals %s damage" % eAttack
    option=raw_input("")
    if enemy.health<=0:
        win()
    if playerIG.health<=0:
        die()
    else:
        fight()

def drinkpot():
    os.system('clear')
    if playerIG.pots==0:
        print "You don't have any potions!"
        option=raw_input("")
        fight()
    else:
        playerIG.health+=50
        if playerIG.health>playerIG.maxhealth:
            playerIG.health=playerIG.maxhealth
        print "You drank a potion"
    option=raw_input("")
    fight()

def run():
    pAttack=random.randint(playerIG.attack/2, playerIG.attack)
    eAttack=random.randint(enemy.attack/2, enemy.attack)
    os.system('clear')
    runnum=random.randint(1,3)
    if runnum==1:
        print "You successfully ran away!"
        option=raw_input("")
        start1()
    else:
        print "You failed to get away!"
        option=raw_input("")
        os.system('clear')
        if eAttack==enemy.attack/2:
            print "The enemy missed!"
        else:
            playerIG.health-=eAttack
            print "The enemy deals %s damage" % eAttack
    option=raw_input("")
    if playerIG.health<=0:
        die()
    else:
        fight()

def win():
    print "You have successfully killed the %s!" % enemy.name
    print "You have gained %s gold!" % enemy.goldgain
    playerIG.gold+=enemy.goldgain
    option=raw_input("")
    start1()

def die():
    print "You have died whilst trying to defeat %s" % enemy.name
    print "1.) Try again"
    print "2.) Quit"
    option=raw_input("-->")
    if option=="1":
        start()
    elif option=="2":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        die()
```

I'm having a problem that when I have another fight the enemy is still the same and still has 0 or less health. I thought that the enemynum would choose a different enemy but it doesn't and I alos don't know how to reset the enemies variables like health back to 70.

Comment: Please only include a [mcve] that shows the malfunctioning part. Do not post your entire project here, nobody wants to analyze pages of foreign code to spot a tiny error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create new instance of enemy each time when it died. In preFight function:

```
def preFight():
    global enemy
    enemynum=random.randint(1,3)
    if enemynum==1:
        enemy=goblin("Goblin")
    elif enemynum==2:
        enemy=zombie("Zombie")
    elif enemynum==3:
        enemy=skeleton("Skeleton")
    fight()
```

Answer (score 1):

Under each enemy class definition, you create an enemy object like this:

```
class goblin():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.maxhealth=50
        self.health=self.maxhealth
        self.attack=5
        self.goldgain=10
goblinIG=goblin("Goblin")
```

But then you only ever refer to that same enemy object when you use prefight().  So, once that object has its health set to 0, it will stay that way, and you just keep referring to it like this:

```
def preFight():
    global enemy
    enemynum=random.randint(1,3)
    if enemynum==1:
        enemy=goblinIG
    elif enemynum==2:
        enemy=zombieIG
    elif enemynum==3:
        enemy=skeletonIG
    fight()
```

You should create new enemy objects each time by doing

```
enemy = goblin("goblin")
```

or whichever one you want to make.